# NullPointerException when extending Log4j Logger class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, log4j

I wanted to add some simple methods to the Log4j logger for use in my application.

Tried doing so like this:

```
public class Logger extends org.apache.log4j.Logger
{
    public Logger(Class type)
    {
        super(type.getName());
    }

    public void info(String format, Object... o)
    {
        info(String.format(format, o));
    }

    public void debug(String format, Object... o)
    {
        debug(String.format(format, o));
    }

    public void warn(String format, Object... o)
    {
        warn(String.format(format, o));
    }

    public void error(String format, Object... o)
    {
        error(String.format(format, o));
    }
}
```

Figured I should be able to use this like so:

```
public class TmpTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Note I'm not even using the special methods here
        new Logger(TmpTest.class).warn("Test");
    }
}
```

But I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.warn(Category.java:1004)
    at no.nwn.productconfigurator.TmpTest.main(TmpTest.java:16)
```

Can I not do it like this? Is there some missing initialization that is done only if I use the `getLogger` factory methods of the `Logger` class?

If I can't extend the Logger class, how should I do it?

---

Could it be something about the log4j.xml? Never used this myself before and haven't written it myself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ProductConfigurator" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <!-- 
      <param name="File" value="logs/ProductConfigurator.log" />   
      -->
      <param name="File" value="/var/tomcat/logs/ProductConfigurator.log" />
      <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}. %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
    <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="ProductConfigurator"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false">
    <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="ProductConfigurator"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="ProductConfigurator"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <!-- all|trace|debug|info|warn|error|fatal|no -->
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="ProductConfigurator"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: I just copied your class and ran the test, but it worked ok

Comment: Strange... added the stack trace now.

Comment: Do your requirements need a Logger or its subclass?

Comment: The proper way to create a Log4J `Logger` is to call one of the static `Logger.getLogger()` methods. The `Logger()` constructor is marked as `protected` for a reason. @gontard has one solution, otherwise you'll need to create your own factory methods.

Answer (score 3):

The `category.repository` field is `null`. Look at the source code :

```
public void warn(Object message) {
    if(repository.isDisabled( Level.WARN_INT))
       return;

    if(Level.WARN.isGreaterOrEqual(this.getEffectiveLevel()))
        forcedLog(FQCN, Level.WARN, message, null);
}
```

To properly initialize a `Logger`, you should use the `LogManager` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{              
    LogManager.getLogger(TmpTest.class.getName(), new LoggerFactory() {

        @Override
        public Logger makeNewLoggerInstance(String name) {
            return new Logger(name);
        }
    }).warn("Test");
}
```

I use a custom factory implementation to instantiate your logger. Not that the classic method to create a logger (`Logger.getLogger(Class clazz)`) use the `LogManager`:

```
static public Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
    return LogManager.getLogger(clazz.getName());
}
```

---

If there isn't specific constraint in your project, i recommend you to use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). It provides the methods that you are expecting :

```
logger.debug("Temperature set to {}. Old temperature was {}.", t, oldT);
```

Comment: I discovered the project actually already depended upon `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-log4j12`. So I deleted my Logger class and used this instead. For some reason the code used org.log4j.Logger directly instead of org.slf4j.Logger. Old messy code I'm trying to clean up :)

Comment: Ok. You will appreciate slf4j. It is a nice api.

Comment: When LoggerFactory gets a logger instance, it checks the cache first before calling makeNewLoggerInstance(). So, be careful that you can't mix and match factories, you need to make sure you haven't got another logger in a different manner using the same name/key.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `super.` in front of all your calls to info, warn, etc.

in the following code :

```
public void info(String format, Object... o) {
    info(String.format(format, o));
}
```

When you call `info(String.format(format, o))`, you call the very same method in a recursive way : the first param is the formatted string, and the second (var-args) param is null, so when `String.format` is called again, you get a NullPointerException.

Therefore you should write this instead :

```
public void info(String format, Object... o) {
    super.info(String.format(format, o));
}
```

Comment: In my example I'm not even calling those methods as far as I can tell. I'm already calling the parent class methods.